# post decrement in while conditon in C

Tags: c, post, while-loop, optimization, decrement

I've done a search and I’ve found nothing relevant to my query.
I am currently debugging a C optimizer and the code in question looks like this:

```
while( x-- )
array[x] = NULL;
```

What should happen in this instance? And should the result of this logic be consistent across all compilers?

Lets say that the initial value of x in this case is 5.

The problem is that the program crashes, my understanding is that it is caused by a negative array element reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The array will never be indexed by a negative value (provided `x` starts of with a non-negative number).  When `x` becomes `0` (followed by the decrement to `-1`), the body will not be executed anyway since a value of `0` is considered false.

Comment: Since the end of the controlling expression of a while loop is a sequence point, I wouldn't expect it to make any difference whether you use post-increment or pre-increment in this case.  Unless I'm missing something I wouldn't expect x to become negative.  Is there more code that might shed a little more light on the subject?

Comment: @Sean: It will make a difference - preincrement will terminate the loop one iteration earlier.

Comment: @Sean: I provided an example in my answer with *unsigned* index. The fact that the index is *unsigned* (if it is) is what makes the post-increment (specifically *post*) important. In any case, if you use pre-increment, the cycle will terminate before processing the `array[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cycle will end with `x` equal to `-1` (assuming `x` is signed), but its body will not produce access to `array[-1]` at the last step. The last array access is to `array[0]`. The behavior is consistent across all implementations.

In other words, there's no problem with negative index array access in the code you quoted. But if you attempt to access `array[x]` immediately after the cycle, then you'll indeed access `array[-1]`.

The code you quoted is a variation of a fairly well-known implementational pattern used when one needs to iterate backwards over an array using an *unsigned* variable as an index. For example

```
unsigned x;
int a[5];

for (x = 5; x-- > 0; )
  a[x] = 0;
```

Sometimes less-experienced programmers have trouble using unsigned indices when iterating backwards over an array. (Since unsigned variables never have negative values, a naive implementation of the cycle termination condition as `x >= 0` does not work.) This approach - i.e. post-increment in the cycle termination condition - is what works in such cases. (Of course, it works with signed indices as well).

Comment: Still I find `for (unsigned x = 5; x <= 5; x--)` much easier to read.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Firstly, in that case it should be `for (unsigned x = 4; x <= 4; ...`. Secondly, the logic behind your condition is not immediately apparent (yes, I know how it works, but nevertheless...). I'd probably prefer `for (unsigned x = 4; x != -1; x--)` instead, although for an unprepared reader the comparison of an *unsigned* variable with `-1` might look confusing as well. The beauty of the last variant is that it also works with signed types.

Comment: right for the `4` instead of `5`. So you see that the original version is really confusing for some people :) `x != -1` is ok for me, still I think that `x <= 4` is a perfect expression that captures exactly the range of the `unsigned` values.

Answer (score 2):

If the initial value of `x` is 5, it will execute:

```
array[4] = NULL;
array[3] = NULL;
array[2] = NULL;
array[1] = NULL;
array[0] = NULL;
```

If `x` is a signed type, then the final value of `x` will be `-1`; otherwise, it will be the maximum value of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `x` is non negative before processing the `while` loop(precondition).
Also `x` value will be -1 when the process leaves the `while` loop(post condition). Therefore, after leaving `while` loop, you should not access the `array` using `x` as index.